# ssrs two datasets used in a list for two matrixs

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS 2005 I have a report with two matrix with two data sets. The report was running fine based when ran on different parameters.

Now I have been asked to modify the report and place another option in the parameter for "All" this will retrieve the results of all parameters and once extracted to Excel it will create different sheets in Excel for based on each parameters results.

For the above purpose I am using a list so each parameter result would be on one page but the problem is when I add the two matrix in the list the second matrix only retrieve values of first data set as the column names are similar. I can provide the second matrix value of second dataset with First(Fields!Site.Value,"Second DataSet") but it obviously picks up only the first value from the second dataset.

I was wondering if there is anyway I can use two datasets in a list and the second dataset picks up all the values and not just only the first value.

Or is there a better way to achieve the above in SSRS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) remove First from this expression : First(Fields!Site.Value,"Second DataSet")

2) your expression should be only =Fields!Site.Value. No need to provide dataset name"Second DataSet".